# Android How to Zoom into Grid View or Gallary View

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing my first android app. I need to be able to zoom into a gridview with 225 images. From what i have come across it is not possible to do horizontal scrolling with a GridView. It is possible to make Gallarys to be scrollable both vertical and horizontal. I have the ability to detect when a user wants to zoom but i am at a lost on how to zoom into one. What would be the best viewgroup to use and any advice on how to zoom would be greatly appreciated